# Selecting XML Node with XPath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xmldocument, selectsinglenode

I have a xml where i want to select a node from it here is the xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
  <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
  <InResponse xmlns="https://ww.ggg.com">
  <InResult>Error </InResult> 
  </InResponse>
  </soap:Body>
  </soap:Envelope>
```

I am loading it using `XmlDocument`'s `LoadXML` and trying to get `InResult` node but I get null see below please:

```
xml.SelectSingleNode("//InResult").InnerText;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a namespace declaration and you should add this into your XPath or you can use namespace agnostic XPath. Try next code as namespace agnostic solution:

```
xml.SelectSingleNode("//*[local-name()='InResult']").InnerText;
```

I've received `Error` as result

From http://www.w3schools.com/ site:

> local-name() - Returns the name of the current node or the first node
>   in the specified node set - without the namespace prefix

You can get more information about XPath functions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp).

Namespace aware solution, is given below:

```
var namespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(x.NameTable);
namespaceManager.AddNamespace("defaultNS", "https://ww.ggg.com");

var result = x.SelectSingleNode("//defaultNS:InResponse", namespaceManager).InnerText;
Console.WriteLine (result); //prints Error
```

**Brief XML notes:**

This part in root note `xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"` is a [xml namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) declaration. It is used to identify nodes in your xml structure. As a rule, you need to specify them to access nodes with it, but there are namespace agnostic solutions in XPath and in LINQ to XML. Now if you see node name as `<soap:Body>`, this means, that this node belongs to this namespace.

Comment: hi, yes it did work can you tell me where is the namespace? is it the xmlns ones?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an namespace issue
You can use an [XmlNamespaceManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) before you call [SelectSingleNode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hw012b.aspx):

```
XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmldoc.NameTable);
ns.AddNamespace("ggg", "https://ww.ggg.com");
xml.SelectSingleNode("//ggg:InResult", ns).InnerText;
```

Attention: Not tested.

Comment: you should pass `ggg` into Xpath, not `ns`. `ns` - is a variable name and XPath evaluation engine knows nothing about it.